# Displaying level in gremlin query

Tags: graph, gremlin, janusgraph

I am executing the gremlin query as follows:

`g.V().hasLabel('A').has('label_A','A').emit().repeat(outE().inV()).valueMap()`

Getting the desired output of nodes at multiple levels.

Along with the properties, I want to add a level property to the output. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer to point out you can avoid `sack` using `loops` as an alternative.

```
g.V().hasLabel('A').has('label_A','A').
      emit().
      repeat(group('x').by(loops()).by(valueMap().fold()).out()).
      cap('x')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withSack` for depth:

```
g.withSack(0).V().hasLabel('A').has('label_A','A').emit().
  repeat(sack(sum).
      by(constant(1)).
    out()).
  project('depth', 'properties').
    by(sack()).
    by(valueMap())
```

example: https://gremlify.com/ca32zczgvtkh6

Comment: Is it possible to modify the query to get the output as follows? Considering root at the zeroth level 1st level nodes as 1.1,1.2,1.3 so on. 2nd level nodes as 1.1.1,1.1.2,1.1.3(for nodes linked to 1.1), 1.2.1,1.2.2,1.2.3(for nodes linked to 1.2). Similarly for other nodes and next levels.

Comment: I added an example to your other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302987/displaying-sub-levels-in-gremlin-query/62324262#62324262